# Asyncronous task execution asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, controls, task, scriptmanager

I have two methods, load and unload, which are as follows:

```
protected Task load()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        controls.AsParallel().Where(control => control is Button).Cast<Button>().ForAll(control =>
        {
            control.Enabled = false;
        });
    });
}

protected Task unload()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        controls.AsParallel().Where(control => control is Button).Cast<Button>().ForAll(control =>
        {
            control.Enabled = true;
        });
    });
}
```

Effectively, they will prevent my web site's user from sending multiple requests. What I'm trying to do is basically: lock up all the button controls, run the function corresponding to the button they've clicked, and then unlock all the button controls. i.e. :

```
protected async void doStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await load();
    await dostuffAsync();
    await unload();
}
```

I am getting no errors, however it simply does everything before the page is updated, so the controls are never disabled. Is this possible to do on asp.net? I have also tried scriptmanager to no avail: it again simply does all the tasks at the same time and then updates the page.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here so I'll try to break it up.

First of all, this shouldn't work. If you do manage to get it to work you'll find your code well into undefined behavior territory and that's the last place you want it from a maintainability standpoint.

Second, asynchronous behavior in web applications can cause all sorts of unwanted behaviors and should not be used lightly. Disabling buttons is not a good reason to add this level of complexity to your application.

Third, if you want to prevent users from submitting forms during processing you should *always* use some kind of client side behavior. jQuery can make these kinds of operations fairly trivial.

Fourth, if you need to prevent the user from performing multiple operations on the server as a security or integrity measure you should restrict access to the *resource* rather than the method which triggers the operation.

Fifth, if at all possible you should discontinue active development in ASP.Net Forms. This doesn't mean you have to rewrite an entire existing application as it is possible to run ASP.Net Forms and MVC side by side. See here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx
The link says ASP.Net MVC 3 but I believe this is still applicable to the latest MVC version.

Comment: How did you know I was using Forms?

Comment: MVC doesn't use the server side controls like Button.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do can't be done with `async` and `await`. `async` yields control to the thread pool, not to the client.

Your best approach is to have JavaScript disable the buttons while the request is in progress and re-enable them when it completes.

P.S. Avoid `Task.Run` and `AsParallel` on ASP.NET; they kill scalability.

Comment: @NykolaiPeterson: As in the ability to handle a greater number of requests on the same hardware.